# com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'alignItems' in shadow node of type: RCTView

Tags: javascript, react-native

using "react-native": "0.62.2"

--------- beginning of crash

> 2020-12-14 20:50:54.996 8624-8819/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 8624
> **com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'text' in shadow node of type:
> RCTRawText** at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:123)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:161)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:65)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:320)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:250)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:469)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
> at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228) at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method
> com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextShadowNode.setText argument
> 1 has type java.lang.String, got java.lang.Boolean at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:109)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:161)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:65)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:320)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:250)
> at
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:469)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
> at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)  at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)  at
> com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tY5h.jpg)